# Slim Framework não esta reconhecendo as sessões salvas

Tags: php, laravel, session, diretório, slimframework

Galera, o meu diretório no slim framework estava padrão..

```
/public
/vendor
/src
/cache
/app
```

entre as outras pastas..
 e dentro da /public A `index.php` estava chamando os outros arquivos e pasta normalmente..

```
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
if(empty(session_id()))
{
    session_start();
}
// Instantiate the app
$settings = require __DIR__ . '/../src/settings.php';
$app = new \Slim\App($settings);
// Set up dependencies
require __DIR__ . '/../src/dependencies.php';
// Register middleware
require __DIR__ . '/../src/middleware.php';
// Register routes
require __DIR__ . '/../src/routes.php';
// Run app
$app->run();
```

Porem tive que mover essas pastas principais para uma subpasta `/v1`

ficando com diretório apenas

```
/public
/v1
```

e com `index.php` dendo de `/public` certamente alterado..

```
    require __DIR__ . '/../v1/vendor/autoload.php';
if(empty(session_id()))
{
    session_start();
}
// Instantiate the app
$settings = require __DIR__ . '/../v1/src/settings.php';
$app = new \Slim\App($settings);
// Set up dependencies
require __DIR__ . '/../v1/src/dependencies.php';
// Register middleware
require __DIR__ . '/../v1/src/middleware.php';
// Register routes
require __DIR__ . '/../v1/src/routes.php';
// Run app
$app->run();
```

Está tudo funcionando exceto as `$_SESSION` gravadas ela se constrói no `AuthModel.php` normalmente mas ao chegar ao `RestrictedController.php`
estão todas vazias..
Sim já verifiquei se existe algum erros nesses arquivos, mas não porque quando estava o diretório padrão estava tudo ok..
 Mas infelizmente preciso usar esse ultimo modelo de diretório dito..
Alguém pode me dar uma luz ai que já nem sei aonde mais procuro erros kkk (msm tvz estando no lugar mais simples)

Comment: Se o problema for realmente na verificação da sessão você pode usar o `session_status()` para verificar se a sessão esta ativa. De uma olhada aqui na [documentação](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php). De qualquer forma, edite a pergunta e seja um pouco mais especifico também, esta dificil de entender seu problema.

Comment: então rapaz, sendo mais direto.. eu apenas coloquei as pastas do slim dentro da pasta v1 direcionei na index.php pra pegar as pastas do slim dentro da v1
e ai parou de gravar a sessão.. e realmente ela esta ativa em todos os diretórios.. mas simplesmente nao esta gravando

Comment: De uma olhada na resposta [desta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8927404/5429980).

Comment: É isso mesmo o problema estava no diretório da sessão, pois como mudei o diretório raiz do projeto não estava localizando o caminho da pasta /tmp
ai mudei usando as configurações descritas na resposta da pergunta `ini_set('session.save_path', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/v1/tmp')`
 e deu tudo certo! Obrigado!